# JavaScript compatible regexp to disallow a zero or any chars?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex to disallow:

```
 0
 0123
 abcd-)(^&%$!"!"£ etc`
```

to allow:

```
1234567890
```

I have the following so far but it fails

> `/^[1-9]|[1-9]\d+$/`

Comment: Just so you know, the reason your regex fails is because the `^` is only being considered for the left option, and the $ is only considered for the right. This would have worked: `/^([1-9]|[1-9]\d+)$` but as jcubic answers it would be best as `/^[1-9]\d*$/`

Comment: If you want to ensure a number, you don't really need a regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regular expression

```
/^[1-9][0-9]*$/
```